# Angular 2 - Using let giving error

Tags: angular

While trying to use **'let'** in angular 2 I am getting this error : *Unexpected Token : A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected.*

```
 let options = new RequestOptions({
      search: new URLSearchParams('XXX') 
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `let` when declaring a class property. You can only use `let` in a block scope e.g. inside a method. Change your code to this:

```
options = new RequestOptions({
      search: new URLSearchParams('XXX') 
  });
```

you can use `public` or `private` modifiers before options if you want. If you dont specify any modifier, then by default it is `public`.